# registerContentObserver() on raw SQLite Cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentresolver

All of the examples I've seen of using `registerContentObserver()` do so through a `ContentProvider` interface. But Cursor has a `registerContentObserver()` call, so I figured maybe the Android folks have put together some deep magic that would allow for getting updates on a `SQLite` cursor when one of the rows from an active result set changed. Either I'm doing it wrong, or there is no such magic. Here's the code I'm working with, the expectation being that when I click on the button to update the value in row #1 I would get an `onChange()` callback. Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    public static final String TAG = "dbtest";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button make = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_make_record);
        make.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyOpenHelper oh = new MyOpenHelper(v.getContext());
                SQLiteDatabase wdb = oh.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("value", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                if (wdb.insert(MyOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv) == -1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to insert row");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Inserted row ");
                }
                wdb.close();
            }
        });

        Button update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_update_record);
        update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyOpenHelper oh = new MyOpenHelper(v.getContext());
                SQLiteDatabase wdb = oh.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("value", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                int count = wdb.update(MyOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id = ?", new String[] {"1"});
                Log.d(TAG, "Updated " + count + " row(s)");
                wdb.close();
            }
        });

        MyOpenHelper oh = new MyOpenHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase rdb = oh.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = rdb.query(MyOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, "_id = ?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        contentObserver = new MyContentObserver(new Handler());
        c.registerContentObserver(contentObserver);
    }

    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        MyContentObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return true;
        }

        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.d(TAG, "Saw a change in row # 1");
        }
    }

    MyContentObserver contentObserver;

    public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "test";
        private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "value TEXT);";

        MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, the accepted answer is wrong, I know it's you own answer but it is not the right one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No takers huh? Well an excellent excuse to dig in myself and figure it out. For those who might be curious after me, if you download the platform source the relevant files to look at are:

frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java
frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java

It looks like the mContentObservable is there to signal different parts of a program running off the cached result set in a Cursor, and the observable is a signal from the cached result set to let consumers know when the cache has been dumped/updated. It doesn't tie into the SQLite implementation to fire events when the underlying datastore is manipulated.

Not exactly surprising, but given the docs I thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: What I don't understand is what makes a ContentProvider special?  If the ContentProvider is backed by a SQLiteDatabase, how does its registerContentObserver() do the right thing?

Comment: It hooks up through the content resolver. When the provider calls notifyChange on the resolver for a uri, the resolver takes care of calling back all observers.

Comment: @jfritz42 a `ContentProvider` is responsible for both reading and writing. So, even if it's backed by an SQLite database, it can call any listeners after persisting write operations.

Comment: What's "special" about a content provider: 1) it's the only way to expose your app data (even files),  in a controlled fashion, to external apps.  2) it is a singleton managed by Android in a way you just can't do on your own, for example if you have multiple process in your app (use a sync adapter) the CP will let you assure a single access to your database is used. Sqlite database is a file, you can't have two helpers use it at the same time (unless you enable write ahead logging)

Answer (score 21):

This is actually possible.

You have to define an **Uri** somewhere (a constant maybe).

I would advice to use something like this:

```java
public static final Uri URI_MY_TABLE = 
    Uri.parse("sqlite://com.example.<your-app-package>/table");
```

Then when you update the database data you call:

```java
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Constants.URI_MY_TABLE, null);
```

And from the **CursorLoader** you are writing do something like:

```java
final ForceLoadContentObserver observer;

public MyCursorLoader(final Context context, ...) {
    super(context);
    // ...
    this.observer = new ForceLoadContentObserver();
}

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor c = queryDatabase(db);
    if (c != null) {
        // Ensure the cursor window is filled
        c.getCount();
        // this is to force a reload when the content change
        c.registerContentObserver(this.observer);
        // this make sure this loader will be notified when
        // a notifyChange is called on the URI_MY_TABLE
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),
            Constants.URI_MY_TABLE);
    }
    return c;
}
```

The **ForceLoadContentObserver** is a public static inner class inside the **Loader** class, if you are using the Support Library it will be *android.support.v4.content.Loader.ForceLoadContentObserver*

In the same **Loader** make sure you *forceReload* if data change:

```java
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (this.cursor != null) {
        deliverResult(this.cursor);
    }
    // this takeContentChanged() is important!
    if (takeContentChanged() || this.cursor == null) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

A good start for your **CursorLoader** if you do not know how to write it is this: [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider)

Your **CursorAdapter** should now be initialized like this:

```java
public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}
```

The **ContentResolver** will take care of notifying observer on the uri you set up.

This is exactly how the *ContentProvider* works.

If you are not using a **Loader** you can do the same stuff, the important modifications are:

- Call *ContentResolver.notifyChange(URI,null);* when you change the data
- Call *Cursor.setNotificationUri(ContentResolver, URI);* when you load the cursor

This way when you register an observer you will be notified when the underling data change.

Comment: Amazing solution Daniele!! Can I do the same thing on iOS?

Comment: I really doubt it Geet Choubey, Loaders and ContentResolver are part of the Android Framework :-)

Comment: is there any latest implementation for this because this was answered 4 years ago.  But this implementation is terrific is there any latest developement on this

Comment: I think you can still use the same thing today. I'm not using loaders anymore, anyway I switched to RxJava and other patterns to handle this kind of stuff.