# Best practices to query SQLite database in ListFragment with CursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter

I'm using Android Compatibility Library in my project. I've set up ListFragment as described in the DevGuide (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), and using a simple CursorLoader Christian made be used without content provider ([CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider/7422343#7422343)).

**The question is** where, in my ListFragment / parent Activity, should I open database, return the Cursor, create Adapter and setListAdapter?

So in my app, I have TitlesFragment, DetailsFragment, FragmentLayoutActivity, DetailsLayoutActivity.

Is the best practice...

- to open database in ListFragment's `onActivityCreated`and close it in ListFragment's `onDestroy` like in code sample below

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      // Open database
      playersDatabaseHelper = new PlayersDBAdapter(getActivity());
      playersDatabaseHelper.open();
      getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
      ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      if (playersDatabaseHelper != null) {
          playersDatabaseHelper.close();
      }
  }
  ```
- query database and return the cursor in `onCreateLoader`, and create the Adapter and setListAdapter in `onLoadFinished` like in code sample below

  ```
  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
      // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
      return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity()) {
          @Override
          public Cursor loadInBackground() {
              playersCursor = playersDatabaseHelper.getAllPlayers();
              return playersCursor;
          }
      };

  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {      
      // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
      playersAdapter = new RowAdapter(getActivity(), playersCursor, R.layout.players_overview_row);

      // Allocate the adapter to the List displayed within this fragment.
      setListAdapter(playersAdapter);

      playersAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

      // The list should now be shown.
      if (isResumed()) {
          setListShown(true);
      } else {
          setListShownNoAnimation(true);
      }
  }
  ```

Am I on the right track or should I move some of those somewhere? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could someone comment on my question please.

Comment: So did you ever get an answer? I'm amazed you have 14 up votes and no answer really.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry no experience in CursorLoader yet and Fragment, but I already experienced use of SQLiteOpenHelper in the context of concurrent access by different threads & activities.

I will assume that PlayersDBAdapter is internally using a SQLiteOpenHelper class. but it is not clear what your methods open() and close() are doing?

What I did:

- define your SQLiteOpenHelper as an *application* wide singleton, not activity wide as you seem to do
- instantiate SQLiteOpenHelper single instance in your Application onCreate
- DON'T release SQLiteOpenHelper  instance in any activity onDestroy, as when an activity stops, another one might still have to open the DB
- I guess SQLiteOpenHelper  instance should be cleared in application onTerminate (not sure as onTerminate is in practice almost never called)
- I have DBAdapter object which gets a SQLiteDatabase reference with mySQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()
- these DBAdapter  are typically allocated in activity onCreate and released in onDestroy

At least this works, no crashs in an application with several thousands users. 
Suggestions to improve that are welcome :-)

Comment: That is indeed a good solution. I have used this method in four of my applications and it works like a charm. I get an occasional error on android 2.2 and below but with 2.3+ it works like a charm.

Comment: My application is compatible from android 1.5 and I have no exception on this. Just experienced rare "SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error" on some specific devices but I assume it is related to issue to Sdcard access or something like that.