# AutoCompleteTextView that can access all the column in a table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem AutoCompleteTextView with SQLITE database. Can you help me out? I want my app can search all the info. in every columns in a table with a simple_spinner_dropdown_item, which really getting me a hard time for I am a beginner.. Can you share it to me? Or give me some links?

Comment: what kind of problems do you have? post the code that is not working

Comment: thank you for answering.....attaching the suggestions in the autocompletetextview from the database

Comment: did you try to use SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.main,cursor, dialect, to, 0);  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);  auto = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocompleteDialect1);
  auto.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  auto.setThreshold(1);

Comment: now use dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider()

Answer (score 0):

dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider() can be used for older versions. From android3.0 this use has been deprecated. U have to cursorloader or u can copy the database content to a arraylist. 
[Best practices to query SQLite database in ListFragment with CursorLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581593/best-practices-to-query-sqlite-database-in-listfragment-with-cursorloader)

Comment: Did u get any success?