# Using CursorLoader to get emails causes duplication of emails

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursorloader

I am trying to get email ids of uses contacts. For that I am using Cursor Loader. There is one problem I am getting duplicate email ids also. How to remove email duplicacy. Should I use raw query "SELECT DISTINCT" instead of using CursorLoader or there is some other solution?

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "  COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP +"='1' AND " + Email.DATA +" IS NOT NULL AND " + Email.DATA +" != \"\" " ;

    //showing only visible contacts  
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into this problem. It appears that the CursorLoader does not have an implementation of "DISTINCT". My workaround adds a few lines to the onLoadFinish method and extends the BaseAdapter to accept a List parameter:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String projection[] = {
            CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };      
    String select = "((" + CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) and " + CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0)";
    String sort = CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(
            mContext, 
            CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            select,
            null,
            sort
            );  

    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> displayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if(!displayNames.contains(name))
            displayNames.add(name);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    mAdapter.swapCursor(displayNames);
}
```

Here is my BaseAdapter class:

```
public class AdapterAddContacts extends BaseAdapter{
private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;

public AdapterAddContacts(Context context,List<String> displayNames){
    mData = displayNames;
    mContext = context;
}   

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(mData != null)
        return mData.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return mData.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_add_contacts,parent,false);

    String data = mData.get(pos);                           

    TextView textName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_contacts_add_display_name);
    textName.setText(data);
    textName.setTag(data);          

    return view;
}   

public void swapCursor(List<String> displayNames){
    mData = displayNames;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You should be able to modify this specifically for your needs.

Comment: Thanks mars, I had used this kind of approach. Was searching for some other solution in which I would not have to use memory.

Comment: I did something similar but used Cursor instead of List.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @mars, I have a solution that does not need a modification of the adapter. The idea is to delete the duplicates of the cursor; as there is no way to do it, we create a new cursor whithout the duplicates.

All the code is in `onLoadFinished`:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        MatrixCursor newCursor = new MatrixCursor(PROJECTION); // Same projection used in loader 
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String lastName = "";
            do {
                if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)).compareToIgnoreCase(lastName) != 0) {

                    newCursor.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2) ...}); // match the original cursor fields
                    lastName =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        mContactsAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }
```

Comment: If item does not contain a DISPLAY_NAME compareToIgnore will have error so it would be good to specify in your cursorLoader's WHERE clause that you are not accepting any Name value that is null.

Answer (score 1):

I used a small hack in my project - an SQL injection, like that:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                "DISTINCT "+ MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME},
            null, null, null);
}
```

This code returns only bundle names and their IDs from Gallery.
So, I'd rewrite your code like that:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {
        "DISTINCT " + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "  COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP +"='1' AND " + Email.DATA +" IS NOT NULL AND " + Email.DATA +" != \"\" " ;

    //showing only visible contacts  
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put [setDistinct](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setDistinct%28boolean%29) in your content provider.

```
    @Override 
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    ...
    final SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setDistinct(true);
```

Comment: The question is regarding CursorLoader, not SQL query

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance and don't want to play around with cursor again in onLoadFinished(), then there is a small hack

I combined following two solutions from SO.

1. [select distinct value in android sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879436/1000864)
2. [CursorLoader with rawQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090140/1000864)

And here is my working solution:

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    String tableName;

    /*
     * Choose the table to query and a sort order based on the code returned
     * for the incoming URI.
     */
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case NOTIFICATION:
            tableName = NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE_NAME;

            break;

        case NOTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP:

            Cursor cursor = db.query(true, NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, TIMESTAMP, null, sortOrder, null);
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

            return cursor;

        case DOWNLOAD:
            tableName = DOWNLOADS_TABLE;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }


    if (selection != null) {
        selection = selection + "=?";
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);


    // Tell the cursor what uri to watch, so it knows when its source data
    // changes
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

If you see in this case Table name is same is first 2 cases but i created a dummy Uri to achieve this. May not be a very good approach but works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
Use `DISTINCT` keyword in selection Array.

```
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, "DISTINCT" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};
```