# ContactContracts get Contacts GroupBy Name Using CursorLoader

Tags: android, group-by, cursor, contactscontract, android-cursorloader

I am retrieving list of contacts using cursorloader but due to the nature of the loader the parameters do not allow for groupby or set distinct.

In my content provider I am able to use setDistinct or groupby in my querybuilder.query functions. However I do not have such access with the ContactsDatabase within the paradigm of the CursorLoader. My implementation is not peculiar in anyway. Simply seeking for someone to point me in the direction of how to approach this situation.

Comment: the answers to this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680865/using-cursorloader-to-get-emails-causes-duplication-of-emails

Comment: @marmor much appreciated.