# LoaderManager delivers results when data source changes

Tags: android

from the [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) it says that one of the loaders characteristics is :

> They monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the
>   content changes.

My question is, how exactly does it do that? can provide me some tutorial or code.. or some kind of explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer on SO:

[Custom CursorLoader notify data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316140/custom-cursorloader-notify-data-change)

Basically you need to register your loader for a callback when the data changed, and then act in it.

I also think this tutorial covers it pretty well:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html  (Check the 'What Makes Up a Loader?' section)

Comment: if i understand the documentation , you must create a broadcast receiver to detect data change ?

Comment: booger i dont think what you wrote is correct... you need a broadcast receiver.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I following [this tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)

And the documentation say:

> In either case, the given
>   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks implementation is associated with the
>   loader, and will be called when the loader state changes. If at the
>   point of this call the caller is in its started state, and the
>   requested loader already exists and has generated its data, then the
>   system calls onLoadFinished() immediately (during initLoader()), so
>   you must be prepared for this to happen. See onLoadFinished for more
>   discussion of this callback
>
> Note that the initLoader() method returns the Loader that is created,
>   but you don't need to capture a reference to it. The LoaderManager
>   manages the life of the loader automatically. The LoaderManager starts
>   and stops loading when necessary, and maintains the state of the
>   loader and its associated content. As this implies, you rarely
>   interact with loaders directly (though for an example of using loader
>   methods to fine-tune a loader's behavior, see the LoaderThrottle
>   sample). You most commonly use the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
>   methods to intervene in the loading process when particular events
>   occur. For more discussion of this topic, see Using the LoaderManager
>   Callbacks.

Comment: that is way to complicated ..and i did not see how this data change call back was performed.

Comment: What did you find difficult? And why do you know how exactly does it? Did you read the complete documentation?