# Show auto suggestion on search bar in android?

Tags: android, search, autocomplete

I am working on android application . I have a searchBar . when I entered any text it should auto suggest me form dictionary of label.

Comment: Show what you had tried so far.?

Answer (score 0):

### Search around: [SO post link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15877582/3326331)

**I have use custom AutoCompleteTextView and add it in ActionBar.**

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
            "France", "France_", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

and Your Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Action Bar:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Edited:

**Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869373/android-cursorloader-sqlite-without-content-provider) and this [link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html) it may help you.** [code is here.](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader)

**Edit:**
More Links for some tutorials [Link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm) ,
[Link 2](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android)

and **FINALLY The One You Asked For**
[Link 3](http://drzon.net/how-to-create-a-clearable-autocomplete-dropdown-with-autocompletetextview/)