# Is there any option to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and respective methods from a `TabActivity`?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabactivity, android-cursorloader

Is there any option to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and respective methods and `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);` from a `TabActivity` ?

I know that `TabActivity` is deprecated, but I can't find a solution without transform all my `Aactivities` into `Fragments` to use a `tabs` and I need to implement a CursorLoader (this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422343/1365895)) on my `TabActivitiy`, if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use TabActivity! It's deprecated!

Use the action bar alternative that you'll be able to use the loaders.