# SimpleCursorLoader onCreateLoader error, return type mismatch

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, loader, mismatch

I am using an SQLite database and wish to load it without using a `ContentProvider`.

I am having trouble getting my subclassed SimpleCursorLoader (taken from [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider)) to work with the `LoaderManager`.

In the overwritten method

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int ID, Bundle args) {
    return new ListCursorLoader(this, dBHelper);

}
```

I get a type mismatch saying that it cannot convert from `ListCursorLoader` to `Loader<Cursor>`. I have tried creating the `ListCursorLoader` on the fly (that is, in the method), but this does not work either.

Here is the code for my `ListCursorLoader`:

```
package utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;

public class ListCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {
    private DBAdapter dBAdapter;

    public ListCursorLoader(Context context, DBAdapter adapter) {
        super(context);
        dBAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override 
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        dBAdapter.open();
        try {
            cursor = dBAdapter.getAllQueries();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.getCount();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have only overwritten the `loadInBackground()` method, and I simply cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried your code and it worked without an issue.

You should double-check your imports. The SimpleCursorLoader you linked to is using the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). You didn't provide the code, but I think you may be using the default LoaderManager, not the one [provided by the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using).

So for you to be able to use this class you need to reference `android.support.v4.content.Loader` and load it using the `SupportLoaderManager` in your Fragment.

Here is the code from my Fragment that worked: 
(Note the use of the support library.)

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
...

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

...

@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        return new ListCursorLoader(this);
    }

...

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that proved to be the mistake!