# Android CursorLoader adding views dynamically in specific/certain order

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view, android-cursorloader

This is probably very odd, but I'm using multiple CursorLoaders in Android to do multiple queries and in the onLoadFinished(), I am adding views like TextViews and ListViews to my layout dynamically based on cursor results like if the cursors were not null. I do get accurate results, but since I'm using AsyncTaskLoader (CursorLoader), the cursor results don't come in at the same time and the results are not added in the correct order. I previously used a static layout and added views at indices and did view.setVisiblity(View.GONE) based on the results, but it was just too much and too confusing because I have like 32 views. Plus it seemed weird because I don't think the user wants to see all of those views going away and moving up and down based on AsyncTaskLoader results.
How can I get the views in the correct order I want them in without having a bunch of boolean variables? I looked into LayoutInflater but that requires indices as well, but I'm not sure that will help me. The problem with indices for me is that in cursorloader ID 1:

```
    view.addView(v, 1);
    view.addView(v, 2);
```

might not get executed until the cursorloader with ID 2 finishes with:

```
    view.addView(v, 3);
    view.addView(v, 4);
```

If cursorLoader ID 1 doesn't get executed and ID 2 does, then there is missing space and I have to do a ton of view.setVisibility(View.GONE) if I use static XML views and do not dynamically add them.

In the code I'm doing something like this currently:

```
     @Override
     public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) { 
     switch (cursorLoader.getId())
     {
           case 0:
                   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                      ..
                      title = new TextView(this);
                      ...
                      mainLinearLayout.addView(title, 1);
                   }
                   break;
           case 1:
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                      ..
                   title2 = new TextView(this);
                   mainLinearLayout.addView(title2, 2);
                   break;
           default:
                   ...
    }
```

}

I also read somewhere online that it is better to use a service instead of cursorloader if you want to do queries on the background thread and have them finish in a certain order, but I have not heard that advice anywhere else or seen any examples doing queries in services. They all use CursorLoader. Is this advice necessarily true? Sounds a bit sketchy.

By the way, I am using the CursorLoader implementation without a content provider given at [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider/7422343#7422343)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the views in the correct order I want them in without
>   having a bunch of boolean variables?

You do need some sort of status control in order to make the views appear in order. I would delegate the view construction/addition to a control class that will have all the information required to make the correct view and in the right order no matter how the loaders finished their jobs.

```
public class ViewDispatcher {
    public SparseArray<Status> mLoadStatuses = new SparseArray<Status>();
    public SparseArray<Cursor> mDataCursors = new SparseArray<Cursor>();

    // you'll call this method for each of the loaders, in the order they should be. The ids should be incremental
    public void registerLoader(int loaderId) {
        mLoadStatuses.put(loaderId, Status.INITIAL);
    }

    // called when one of the loaders finishes its job
    public void onLoadComplete(int loaderId, Cursor data) {
         mDataCursors.put(loaderId, data);
         boolean current = true;
         mLoadStatuses.put(loaderId, Status.LOADED);
         if (loaderId == firstLoaderId) {
            // the first loader it's done and we should start the view creation right away
            buildView(loaderId, mainLayout, true);
            mLoadStatuses.put(loaderId, data, Status.FULLY_BUILT);          
         } else {
           // implement a priority system, a view construction will be triggered ONLY 
           // if the previous loader has finished loading data and its view is in place
           // I'm assuming that the Loaders have consecutive ids
           if (mLoadStatuses.get(loaderId - 1) != null && mLoadStatuses.get(loaderId - 1) == Status.FULLY_BUILT) {
               buildView(loaderId, data, mainLayout, true); 
               mLoadStatuses.put(loaderId, Status.FULLY_BUILT);    
            } else {
               current = false;
            } 
         }  
         // we'll also need to implement a buddy system. When a loader is done loading and its view
         // is created we must check to see if we don't have other loaders after this current one that have finished loading 
         // but couldn't construct their view because this current loader didn't finished at that moment
         // get the next loader
         int next = loaderId + 1;
         while(current && next < totalNumberOfLoaders && mLoadStatuses.get(next) == Status.LOADED) {
            // continue to build views
            buildView(next, mDataCursors.get(loaderId), mainLayout, true);              
            mLoadStatuses.put(next, Status.FULLY_BUILT);
            next++; 
         } 
    }  

    // this will build the appropriate view, and optionally attach it
    public void buildView(int loaderId, Cursor data, view mainLayout, boolean attach) {
        // build the view for this specific Loader
    }

}

public enum Status {
    INITIAL, LOADED, FULLY_BUILT 
}
```

I hope I'm not missing something obvious as I wrote that without any tests. To use it, you'll first call the `registerLoader()` method for all loaders in the order you need them to be and in the `onLoadComplete()` callback of the `LoaderCallbacks` call `ViewDispatcher.onLoadComplete()`.

> I also read somewhere online that it is better to use a service
>   instead of cursorloader if you want to do queries on the background
>   thread and have them finish in a certain order, but I have not heard
>   that advice anywhere else or seen any examples doing queries in
>   services.

You've probably read about `IntentService` which can be made to follow a queue through the order of the `Intents` it receives. But, I don't see how this would help you as it would just add problems. For one you use `Cursors` as the data holders that you would need to pass back and you need to create views which the `IntentService` can't do(it will need to make the `Activity` create them through various communication ways, this is unnecessary work from my point of view).

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, I have a few more questions about the code. How do you get the total number of loaders at run-time? (the next < totalNumberOfLoaders line) If I define the number statically, would it mess it up? What is the difference between mLoadloaderId and the one given in the method in this case? Also, It doesn't seem that you can add cursor data to the SparseArray, but I don't think it's needed?

Comment: @John61590 `mLoadloaderId` was a typo, it's the `loaderId` parameter of the method. *How do you get the total number of loaders at run-time?* - well, I assumed you have a fixed number of loaders a number that you know at start. If the number is dynamic then you would need to change the data structure to hold separately the order and the state. You don't need the `Cursor` in the `SparseArray` it will be passed in the `onLoadComplete()` method and from there you could use it.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't seem to be working for me because of this section: `int next = loaderId + 1;
        while(current && next < 3 && mLoadStatuses.get(next) == Status.LOADED) {
            // continue to build views
            buildView(next, data, mainLL, true);
            mLoadStatuses.put(next, Status.FULLY_BUILT);
            next++;
        }`

Comment: In my case, the `mLoadStatuses.get(next) == Status.LOADED` is true in the same method that another loader went through and because the other loader went through ` if (mLoadStatuses.get(loaderId - 1) != null && mLoadStatuses.get(loaderId - 1) == Status.FULLY_BUILT) {` i end up using the wrong cursor for the wrong ID

Comment: Example LogCat: `loaderID in onLoadComplete at the beginning is 1`
`in mLoadStatus.get(loaderId - 1) if statement`
`mLoadStatuses.get(loaderId - 1) is FULLY_BUILT`
`loaderId in mLoadStatuses is 1`
`cursor in mLoadStatues is android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@415143e8`
`get column names in ke_pri [_id, ke_priValue]`
`in current while loop`
`next is 2`
`in re_inf in buildView`
`get column names in re_inf is [_id, ke_priValue]`

Comment: @John61590 Yes, that while loop will not work. You could use the same approach to store the cursors. See the edited code.

Comment: seems to work but i had to change `buildView(next, mDataCursors.get(next), mainLL, true);` and not `mDataCursors.get(loaderId)`. Now to figure out why I keep getting Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord =/

Comment: @John61590 I'm sleepy:) Regarding the activity pause timeout it may be related to all those started loaders(maybe if you start the loaders in batches(like 5 at a time and then wait 2 seconds for example before starting the next batch)).