# android chat application, how to update database real time?

Tags: android, chat, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I am making a chat application on android.

The way I have set up my app is that each phone stores the messages locally. I will then have the app connect to a server to make sure that the databases on the phone are in line with the databases on the server. I haven't programmed the server section yet.

What I have done is created a `ListFragment` where the messages are displayed through a custom cursor loader. I followed the instructions for that here: [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider)

On the activity page where my Fragment exists, there is an edit text and a send button. Typing something and clicking send will start an intent which adds the message to the database, then returns to the same page. However this causes the entire activity to refresh, which doesn't look good for a chat application.

How would I have that database of messages update in realtime?

Comment: i think you have to implement push notification for this

Comment: @r4jiv007 do you have a link which describes this more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what I am looking for is called Google Cloud Messaging. More information is available at the below link.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: yeah that has push messaging .. u can also look at "parse" they also provide push related service