# When to use cursor loaders?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

When I use SQLite to bring my data and use cursor and adapters, should I use cursor Loaders??. Is this the best practice?. Im not quite clear when to use cursor loaders. Should I use it only if my app shares data with other apps?. My question comes because it have been really annoying for me using cursors + adapters + listView; sometimes the notifyDataSetChanged works, sometimes not, so it have been really tricky sometimes. I start reading about cursor loaders but Im not sure if this is a work around for this in particular or if I can use it as a work around.

Any clarification will be really appreciated!!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Loaders to ensure that all cursor operations are done asynchronously, thus eliminating the possibility of blocking the UI thread.

When using CursorAdapter don´t use notifyDataSetChanged instead use:

```
db.updateData();
yourCursor = db.getData();  
yourAdapter.changeCursor(yourCursor);
```

Comment: so, should I use cursors loaders? even when my app wont share its database with other apps?

Comment: Cursor loaders don't enable database share. If you want share database with other apps use ContentProvider see [this](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1375/android_content_provider_tutorial). Cursor loaders are introduced with Android 3.0 to facilitate cursor operations asynchronously. If you only read small chunks of data is ok not use cursor loaders. Read [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) to more on cursor loaders

Comment: I mentioned the database sharing because cursor loaders uses contentProviders and contentPorviders as you said are used to share data between apps. Thats why Im confuse, but no I dont need to share database. So, should  I use cursor loaders only if a have a large database?

Comment: Can I use cursor loaders without using contentProviders?

Comment: No. But you can do some similar see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7422343/2556111)

Comment: Thanks a lot ramaral, your posts have been really helpful! :).