# Bind ListView with Cursor in Android

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have `Cursor` which contains data as below :

```
OptionId    Option     QId      Answer
   1        test1       1         0
   2        test2       1         1
   3        test3       1         0
   4        test4       1         0
```

Now, I want to bind all these data to `ListView`. And `onClick()`, I want value of OptionId, QId and Answer.

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider

Comment: and did you read a Notepad tutorial?

Comment: @pskink, Notepad tutorial ? Whats it ?

Comment: @BSKANIA, i dont think so it is related to my question. I want to show `Cursor` data in `ListView`.

Comment: link http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html