# Join and display the results of two tables in onCreateLoader - Android Content Provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper

I want to create an activity called `TableAandTableBActivity` that will display the following information from my DB:

```
Select * from TableA, TABLEB where TableA._ID = TABLEB.productid
```

(Here _ID = product id)

I'm not sure how to do this. In my Content Provider class I created a static initialiser that joins tableA and TABLEB `where TableA._ID = TABLEB.productid` like this:

```
 static{
           sTableAWithTABLEB = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

           //This is an inner join which looks like
           //TableA INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TableA.id = TABLEB.TableA_id
           sTableAWithTABLEB.setTables(
                   TableAContract.TableAEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                           TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                           " ON " + TableAContract.TableAEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                           "." + TableAContract.TableAEntry._ID +
                           " = " + TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                           "." + TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.COLUMN_TableA_ID);
       }
```

I started writing the code to display the results of my query in `onCreateLoader` in `TableAandTableBActivity` but now stuck. Please can someone show me how to solve this issue.  Here are my code snippets:

```
public class TableAandTableBActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_TABLEB);
   }

   @Override
   public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
       // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
       String[] projection = {
               TableAContract.TableAEntry._ID,
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.COLUMN_TableA_NAME,
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.COLUMN_TableA_QUANTITY,
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.COLUMN_TableA_CATEGORY,
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.COLUMN_TableA_PRICE};


       // Here is where I want to display the results of Select * from TableA, TABLEB where TableA._ID = TABLEB.productid
       return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
               projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
               null,                   // No selection clause
               null,                   // No selection arguments
               null);                  // Default sort order
   }

   @Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

   }
}



//

public class TableAProvider extends ContentProvider {

   private static final String LOG_TAG = TableAProvider.class.getSimpleName();
   static final int TableA = 100;
   private static final int TableA_ID = 101;
   static final int TABLEB = 200;
   private static final int TABLEB_ID = 201;
   static final int TableA_WITH_TABLEB = 300;
   private TableADbHelper mDbHelper;


   private static final SQLiteQueryBuilder sTableAWithTABLEB;


   private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

   static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

       final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
       final String authority = TableAContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

       matcher.addURI(authority, TableAContract.PATH_TableA, TableA);
       matcher.addURI(authority, TableAContract.PATH_TableA + "/#", TableA_ID);
       matcher.addURI(authority, TableAContract.PATH_TABLEB, TABLEB);
       matcher.addURI(authority, TableAContract.PATH_TABLEB + "/#", TABLEB_ID);
       matcher.addURI(authority, TableAContract.PATH_TableA + "/*", TableA_WITH_TABLEB);
       return matcher;
   }


   static{
       sTableAWithTABLEB = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

       //This is an inner join which looks like
       //TableA INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TableA.id = TABLEB.TableA_id
       sTableAWithTABLEB.setTables(
               TableAContract.TableAEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                       TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                       " ON " + TableAContract.TableAEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                       "." + TableAContract.TableAEntry._ID +
                       " = " + TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                       "." + TableAContract.TABLEBEntry.COLUMN_TableA_ID);
   }



//

public final class TableAContract {

   private TableAContract() {
   }

   public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.test.androidtwotaabl.es";
   public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

   public static final String PATH_TableA = "TableA";
   public static final String PATH_TABLEB = "TABLEB";

   public static final class TableAEntry implements BaseColumns {

       public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_TableA);
       public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE =
               ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_TableA;
       public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
               ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_TableA;

       public final static String TABLE_NAME = "TableA";
       public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_NAME = "TableAName";
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_QUANTITY = "TableAQuantity";
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_PRICE = "TableAPrice";
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_CATEGORY = "TableACategory";
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_OLDPRICE = "oldPrice";

       public static Uri TableAWithTABLEB() {
           return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_TABLEB).build();
       }

   }

   public static final class TABLEBEntry implements BaseColumns {
       public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_TABLEB);
       public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE =
               ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_TABLEB;
       public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
               ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_TABLEB;

       public final static String TABLE_NAME = "TABLEB";
       public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
       public final static String COLUMN_TableA_ID = "TableAId";
   }

}
```

Comment: `"but now stuck"`, where? what do you have problems with?

Comment: The content provider is [unnecessary complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/cursorloader-usage-without-contentprovider).

Comment: @pskink in my oncreateLoader how do i display the results of two joined tables?

Comment: you have a `Cursor` with your "joined tables" data, right? so use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and attach it to your `ListView` (or use similar adapter when using `RecyclerView`)

Comment: @pskink yes I have an adapter already. I still don't get it. do I need to create a separate URi for the two joined tables

Comment: if you want data from one table only you can create separate Uri, but if you only want a "joined" results use just one Uri

Comment: ah i think that is where the problem is. how do i build my cursor with two joined tables?

Comment: so you dont know how to create a query with a [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm) statement?

Comment: yes I dont know

Comment: so use `sqlite3` tool and play with the sample queries presented in a link i posted above

Comment: okay but I thouhght  my static initiliaser in TableAProvider already does the join though.

Comment: does your query work in `sqlite3`?

Comment: no because I'm not sure how to make it work in my oncreateloader

Comment: first learn how to build working SQL query, then do any java / android stuff

Comment: thanks @pskink. it would be great if you have examples that shows joining two tables using a content provider

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm