# android.database.Cursor registerContentObserver

Tags: android, sqlite

Here the the description of registerContentObserver :

abstract void   registerContentObserver(ContentObserver observer)

Register an observer that is called when changes happen to the content backing this cursor.

Here is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor)dataBase.query(projection, null, null, null);
cursor .registerContentObserver(new ChangeObserver());

private class ChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public ChangeObserver() {
        super(new Handler());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "ChangeObserver.onChange");
    }
}
```

However when I change the database(delete/update/add row), the onChange method of ContentObserver will never be called. 
So I want to know what's the situation will trigger the ContentObserver ?

Comment: did you call  getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange() in your insert/update methods and Cursor.setNotificationUri() in the query() method of your ContentProvider?

Comment: No, it do nothing with content resolver.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, it's a problem in the documentation, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6470941/1337498) -- and hats off to @mikerowehl for doing the research!

It boils down to the documentation having been written mostly to describe the behavior of Cursors that work with ContentProviders/ContentResolvers. If these classes are not involved, and not manipulated as suggested by @Renard, the ContentObserver won't get a callback. Despite what the documentation says.

Hence, the raw SQLiteCursor is kind of a "poor relation" to those *fancy* Cursors... :)